# APINotAllowedError while getting post via Instagram API

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, instagram, instagram-api

I have trying to get posts from user with instagram

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/1481746871/media/recent/?access_token=*censored*&count=6

I already tried using url above on my browser and it has responded what I wanted, but when i tried it on laravel, it returs
APINotAllowedError 400 you cannot view this resource

this is my code :

```
function callInstagram($url)
            {
                $ch = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
                    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2
                ));

                $result = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);
                return $result;
            }

$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/317657774/media/recent/?access_token=*censored*&count=6';

$inst_stream = callInstagram($url);
$results = json_decode($inst_stream, true);
return $results;
```

I wonder why ? is it because I am testing from localhost and it is not https ?

please note that I am using my own account(non private) and access_token is generated from my own account

thanks !

Comment: Can you try it in both your browser and Laravel with the same user?

Comment: This doesn't look to me like a POST request. Make sure you're actually doing what the docs describe. Most likely there is already a library that will communicate with instagram for you.

Comment: actually it was working fine until just now

with the very same code of course

Comment: it is also working on my browser by inputting the url directly
returned all the data

but when I use it on laravel, it doesnt work, returning 404

Comment: Both of those URL's are different.  I'm assuming the one you are using in Laravel is the wrong one.

Comment: unfortunately, i just confirmed it is perfectly same

Comment: URL's have different `userId`s. First one from private account wich gives `{
    "error_type": "APINotAllowedError",
    "code": 400,
    "error_message": "you cannot view this resource"
  }`.